# Проблемы со Scanner'ом в Java

Tags: java, scanner

```java
package z_1;

import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Z_1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        File fileIn = new File("in.txt");
        File fileOut = new File("out.txt");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner fin = new Scanner(fileIn);
        String str;

        while (true) {
            System.out.print("Введите команду (1 - ввод данных, 2 - просмотр данных, 3 - программа завершает работу): ");
            int a = in.nextInt();
            switch (a) {
                case 1:
                    PrintWriter fout1 = new PrintWriter(fileIn);
                    System.out.print("Введите последовательность: ");
                    while (in.hasNextInt()) {
                        int b = in.nextInt();
                        fout1.print(b + " ");
                    }
                    str = in.next();
                    fout1.close();
                    break;

                case 2:
                    if (!fileIn.exists()) {
                        System.out.println("Такого файла не существует");
                    }

                    int num;
                    while (fin.hasNextInt()) {
                        num = fin.nextInt();
                        System.out.print(num + " ");
                    }
                    System.out.print("\n");
                    break;
                case 3:
                    System.exit(0);
                    break;            
             }
        }
    }  
}
```

> После ввода данных файл (case 1) хочу вывести на экран цифры содержащиеся в нём(case 2), первый раз получается это сделать, а вот второй уже нет, в чём проблема?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Определите сканер fin внутри блока 'case 2' и закрывайте его после каждого прочтения данных из файла.

```
                case 2:
                Scanner fin = new Scanner(fileIn); // <--
                if (!fileIn.exists()) {
                    System.out.println("Такого файла не существует");
                }

                int num;
                while (fin.hasNextInt()) {
                    num = fin.nextInt();
                    System.out.print(num + " ");
                }
                System.out.print("\n");
                fin.close(); // <--
                break;
```